# Reading and grouping uncertain sized arrays in Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have a file with some strings on it. Every group in this file has two IDs and I thought I can separate these groups with where those ID lines are.I created a method for checking if the string begins with a number character or not.Then i saved index numbers of those strings in `integers`.

Now I want to create objects from this data with these IDs they have and an arraylist that contains these group of strings.
Example file format:

```
1   4
str1
str2
2   11
str3
str4
str5
5   7
str6
str7
str8
7   90
str9
```

The code i was trying to make it work

```java
    @Override
    public void readFile(String path) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
            ArrayList<String> temporaryArray = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                temporaryArray.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            for (String string : temporaryArray) {
                if (ifExistOnArray(string.charAt(0))) {
                    integers.add(temporaryArray.indexOf(string));
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
                String[] numline = temporaryArray.get(integers.get(i)).split("\t");
                int firstID = Integer.parseInt(numline[0]);
                int secondID = Integer.parseInt(numline[1]);
                ArrayList<String> objectLines = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = integers.get(i); j < integers.get(i+1) - 1; j++) {
                    objectLines.add(temporaryArray.get(j+1));
                }
                Admission admission = new Admission(firstID, secondID, objectLines);
                IOOperations.admissionArrayList.add(admission);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And the method i used for checking whether the line starts with a number or not.

```java
public boolean ifExistOnArray(char ch) {
        char[] chars = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        boolean found = false;
        for (char iterate : chars) {
            if(ch == iterate) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Code gives `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `for (int j = integers.get(i); j < integers.get(i+1); j++) {` line and i understand why it does so but i can't think of any solution to make it work. What should i do to make this code work?

Comment: user19281 - Any update?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Hi thank you for answering.In my initial thought integers array would store indexes of  lines that start with a digit. And temporaryArray would store all lines and in the loop I would operate creation of objects but after seeing Christian Bongiorno's answer I thought using LinkedHashMap could be a better idea. But thanks for pointing out use of \\s+ and isDigit i am using them now.

Answer (score 1):

Address the following points:

1. You do not need the following code

   ```
   public boolean ifExistOnArray(char ch) {
       char[] chars = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
       boolean found = false;
       for (char iterate : chars) {
           if(ch == iterate) {
               found = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       return found;
   }
   ```

   You can use `Character.isDigit(ch)` instead e.g. `Character.isDigit('4')` will return `true`.
2. Split on `\\s+` instead of `\t`.
3. The following loop does not make sense to me. How are the values inside `temporaryArray` related to those inside `integers`?

   ```
   for (int j = integers.get(i); j < integers.get(i+1) - 1; j++) {
       objectLines.add(temporaryArray.get(j+1));
   }
   ```

   Irrespective of that, if you are using `temporaryArray.get(j+1)`, the loop condition must have a check for the index of `temporaryArray` from which you are trying to get a value i.e. it should be

   ```
   for (int j = integers.get(i); j < temporaryArray.size() - 1 && j < integers.get(i+1) - 1; j++)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I tried really hard to come up with a functional approach in Java, but I don't know of a functional approach that wouldn't have me filling in the blanks in java's functional world and actually writing more code. So, here is the imperative approach:

```java
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("sample.txt")));

Map<String,List<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String lastKey = null;

for(String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()){
    if(line.matches("\\d+[ ]+\\d+")){
        lastKey = line;
    }
    else{
        result.computeIfAbsent(lastKey,k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(line);
    }
}
result.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.format("(%s) -> %s%n",k,v));
```

Yields:

```
(1   4) -> [str1, str2]
(2   11) -> [str3, str4, str5]
(5   7) -> [str6, str7, str8]
(7   90) -> [str9]
```